# sendmsg or sendmmsg for pure L2 packets

Tags: c, sockets

I want to send pure L2 packets using RAW sockets. 
As i wish to send multiple packet in single SEND system call, i am intended use sendmmsg.

I understand how to allocate buffer and fill struct msghdr and struct iovec.
But I always get error from sendmmsg   "No such device or address"

Do i have to update any other members of this structure, apart from iov and iovlen

```
struct msghdr 
{
    void    *msg_name;      
    socklen_t    msg_namelen;   
    struct iovec    *msg_iov;       
    size_t    msg_iovlen;    
    void    *msg_control;   
    size_t    msg_controllen;
    int    msg_flags;     
};
```

Do i have to update my interface index or SRC MAC  or Destination MAC in this struct msghdr explicitly.

Data that I assign in iov_base is compete L2 frame (with src and dest MAC etc..)

Could some help me here ............

Answer (score 0):

Raw sockets allow to send L3 packets, i.e IP layer packets bypassing the L4 transport layer.
Ex. ICMP protocol uses RAW sockets.

If you need to send an L2 packet, you need to have kernel module which allocates an skb(socket buffer) and populates with all the details for ex, SOURCE mac, DESTINATION mac, protocol type, outgoing interface and hand it to the driver for transmission over the appropriate interface.

You also may need to have a communication channel(netlink socket or simple char driver) for communication between your user level application and kernel module.
Socket calls like send, sendmsg don't help to do what you are trying.